# 2 source of SetOnClickListener in c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, onclicklistener

how can I determine from which source onClick of IOnClickListener is triggered?

I have this initialization of SetOnClickListener

```
    private void setUpListener()
    {
        changePassword.SetOnClickListener(this);
        forgotPassword.SetOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

what i want to happen is

```
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if(source == changePassword)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChangePassword));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(source == forgotPassword)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForgotPassword));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnClick method, put a switch case with the View v and specify the cases with the specific id assigned to the said views.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: oh one more thing make sure to v.GetId in the switch

Comment: there's no GetId :) but thanks :) i'm now trying your first answer . v.Id is existing though

Comment: yes v.Id then in your cases use R.id.change_password

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer ! :D Thanks to @Mike :) although some of comments are not really existing in C# (probably it's an android coding) but it helps though !

getting the id sent in View by v.Id is great
then comparing it with my textView ID using Resource.Id.txtChangePassword made it running

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        int id = v.Id; //get id here
        if (id == Resource.Id.txtChangePassword) //comparison
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChangePassword));
            intent.PutExtra(IntentExtras.activitySourceSerialized, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Strings.loginActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(id == Resource.Id.txtForgotPassword) //comparison
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForgotPassword));
            intent.PutExtra(IntentExtras.activitySourceSerialized, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Strings.loginActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**CHEERS!!!**